# Trouble implementing deletion in Binary Search Tree in python

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I have implemented a deletion function of Binary Search Tree. The idea is to declare a private function that takes an extra parameter to abstract down        `self.root` to `root`. In the private delete function, it will do condition check and make sure `root` equals to the data needs to be deleted. After condition check, I write the 3 different cases of deletions. No error message when I compile the code, nor does it delete any inserted node.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None, parent=None):
        self.left = left  
        self.data = data
        self.right = right   


class Tree(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Node(None)

    def delete(self,newData):
        if self.root.data == None:
            print 'The tree is empty'
        else:
            self.__delete(self.root, newData)

    def __delete(self, root, newData):
        # if newData smaller than root.data, change root to root.left, recursive call
        if newData < root.data:
            if root.left:
                self.__delete(root.left, newData)
            else:
                return False
        # if newData larger than root.data, change root to root.right, recursive call
        elif newData > root.data:
            if root.right:
                self.__delete(root.right, newData)
            else:
                return False
        elif newData == root.data:
            #case 1, root has no child
            if root.left is None and root.right is None:
                root = None
            #case 2, root has one child (left)
            elif root.left is not None and root.right is None:
                root.data = root.left.data
                root.left = None
            #case 3, root has one child (right)
            elif root.right is not None and root.left is None:
                root.data = root.right.data
                root.right = None
            #case 4, root has both children,
            # find the smallest node in the right subtree, and swipe value
            # delete smallest node in the right subtree
            else:
                root.data = self.__minValueToRightSubtree(root.right).data
                self.__deleteMinValueToRightSubtree(root.right)
        else:
            print "Can't find this number"

    def __minValueToRightSubtree(self, root):
        if root.left is None:
            return root
        else:
            return self.__minValueToRightSubtree(root.left)

    def __deleteMinValueToRightSubtree(self, root):
        if root.left is None:
            root = None
            return root
        else:
            self.__minValueToRightSubtree(root.left)
```

Comment: What does this code do wrong that you are not expecting? I can tell you that Case 2 and 3 root-delete are wrong because you keep `root.left` and `root.right` pointers when you attempt to delete the root.

Comment: hey there. So my thought in those cases are, copy the data from `root.left.data` or `root.right.data` to `root.data`, and delete the left/right node. I didn't receive any error message with this block of code, and the code doesn't do anything, so I am very clueless. Can you elaborate why case 2/3 are implemented wrong after reading my though process

Comment: Read this over... `elif root.right is not None and root.left is None`, then read this `root.left = None`

Comment: Anyways, 1) Pycharm has a nice debugger. 2) Write your algorithm "on paper" for many different trees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, none of your recursive function's base cases work correctly. There are two kinds of errors (each repeated twice, with some variation):

The first issue is pretty simple. In cases 2 and 3, you're copying the data from the single child node, then deleting your reference to that node. However, this won't do the right thing if the child node has children of its own. Perhaps you can assume it doesn't have children if your tree is guaranteed to be balanced, but for a general BST, you can't assume that. A better version would be:

```
        #case 2, root has one child (left)
        elif root.left is not None and root.right is None:
            root.data = root.left.data
            root.right = root.left.right
            root.left = root.left.left
        #case 3, root has one child (right)
        elif root.right is not None and root.left is None:
            root.data = root.right.data
            root.left = root.left.left
            root.right = root.left.right
```

The other issue is more subtle. The thing is, you can't delete `root` the way you're trying to do in case 1 (and in case 4 in the `__deleteMinValueToRightSubtree` helper method). You are assigning `None` to `root`, which might work if Python passed arguments the same way C++ and Java do (by reference). But Python does arguments differently than those languages. Python arguments are passed "by assignment", which means the argument you have in the function is a local variable, bound to the same object the caller passed in. When you do `root = None`, you're only modifying your local variable, and not the tree structure.

There are a variety of ways you can fix this. Which way is best will depend a bit on the other details of your implementation.

If your `Node` objects have `parent` references, then you can use those to unlink a node from its parent (though you'll need a special case for the root node which doesn't have a parent). I see a `parent` argument to the `Node` constructor, but you don't seem to be using it. If you hooked that up, the code for removing a node would be relatively easy.

```
        #case 1, root has no child
        if root.left is None and root.right is None
            if root.parent is None: # root is the root node of the whole tree
                self.root = None
            elif root.parent.left is root:
                root.parent.left = None
            else: # elif root.parent.right is root:
                root.parent.right = None
        #...
        #case 4, root has both children,
        # find the smallest node in the right subtree, and swipe value
        # delete smallest node in the right subtree
        else:
            min_right_node = self.__minValueToRightSubtree(root.right)
            root.data = min_right_node.data       # no need to recurse twice
            if min_right_node is self.right:      # we can use the same node reference for
                self.right = None                 # both steps (swiping value and deleting)
            else:
                min_right_node.parent.left = min_right_node.right
```

If you don't have parent links, you can change the logic of the recursion instead, so that you `return` a modified tree, which the caller assigns to the node it was recursing on. This would require you to change your error handling, since the return value is being used for something else than signalling success or failure. I'd suggest raising an exception if the target isn't found.

```
def delete(self,newData):
    if self.root.data == None: # should this be testing `self.root is None`?
        print 'The tree is empty'
    else:
        self.root = self.__delete(self.root, newData) # use return value

def __delete(self, root, newData):
    # if newData smaller than root.data, change root to root.left, recursive call
    if newData < root.data:
        if root.left:
            root.left = self.__delete(root.left, newData)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Can't find this number")
    # if newData larger than root.data, change root to root.right, recursive call
    elif newData > root.data:
        if root.right:
            root.right = self.__delete(root.right, newData)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Can't find this number")
    elif newData == root.data:
        #case 1, root has no child
        if root.left is None and root.right is None:
            return None
        #case 2, root has one child (left)
        elif root.left is not None and root.right is None:
            return root.left
        #case 3, root has one child (right)
        elif root.right is not None and root.left is None:
            return root.right
        #case 4, root has both children,
        # find the smallest node in the right subtree, and swipe value
        # delete smallest node in the right subtree
        else:
            root.right, root.data = __delete_min(root.right)
            return root
    else:
        print "Can't find this number"

def __delete_min(self, root): # returns a (node, minimum value) 2-tuple
    if root.left is None:
        return root.right, root.data
    else:
        root.left, minval = self.__delete_min(root.left)
        return root, minval
```

A final word about naming: It's a bad idea to use double leading underscore names for private functions. That syntax invokes Python's "name mangling" system, which transforms the names to refer to the class where the code referencing them is defined. It's useful when you're writing a mixin or proxy class, and you can't know ahead of time what attributes might collide. For normal code though, it just makes things annoying. If you want to mark a method as private, just use one leading underscore. This doesn't do anything at the language level, but it is a convention. Other programmers (and documentation tools) will know that a function named that way is not part of a public API. (Another, perhaps weaker, convention is to use `lowercase_names_with_underscores` rather than `camelCaseNames` for most variables and methods. This is much more a style issue, not something that's actually harmful to using the code, like the name mangling can be.)

Comment: Blckknght, thank you so much! It really makes a lot more sense now, I was kind of thinking the problem might issues from pass by reference, but I was clueless how to fix it. Thanks for the insight, this answer is so informative!

Comment: I just finished implementing the code using parent method, and it worked! Just a quick question on your delete min function. when you return the node back and assign it to a new variable, `min_right_node`. Did you make a copy of the node, or you actually return the reference to this variable, because it would make sense when you pass the reference back, so when you call `min_right_node.parent.left`, it actually deleles the node from the tree rather than delete the copy variable

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand which of my implementations you're asking about. There's no copying of nodes going on anywhere. I do see an error in the last line of the second code block. `min_right_node.parent.left = None` should be `min_right_node.parent.left = min_right_node.right`, since the minimum node is not necessarily a leaf node (it can't have a left child or it wouldn't be the minimum, but it can have a right child). I'll edit to correct that.